# Why CLARA clustering method does not give the same classes as when I do clustering manually?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am using CLARA (in 'cluster' package). This method is supposed to assign each observation to the closest 'medoid'. But when I calculate the distance of medoids and observations manually and assign them manually, the results are slightly different (1-2 percent of occurrence probability). Does anyone know how clara calculates dissimilarities and why I get different clustering results?

This is the function I use to do clustering manually:

```
Manual.Clustering <- function(Data,Clusters,Weights=NULL) {

if (is.null(Weights))   Weights <- rep(1,length(Data));
if (length(Weights)==1) Weights <- rep(Weights,length(Data));

Data2 <- Data[,rownames(Clusters)];
Data2 <- Weights*Data2;
dist  <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(Data),ncol=ncol(Clusters));

for (i in 1:ncol(Clusters)) {
    dist[,i] <- Dist2Center(Data2,Clusters[,i],Weights=NULL);
}

classes <- apply(dist,1,which.min);
Out <- cbind(Data,classes);
colnames(Out) <- c(colnames(Data),"Class");
Freq <- FreqTable(Out[,"Class"]);
Freq <- as.data.frame(Freq);

return(list(Data=Out,Freq=Freq));
}
```

=====================================

```
Dist2Center <- function(Data,Center,Weights=NULL) {

if (is.null(Weights))   Weights <- matrix(rep(1,nrow(Data)),ncol=1);
if (length(Weights)==1) Weights <- rep(Weights,nrow(Data));

if (ncol(Data)!=length(Center)) stop();

Dist <- Weights*apply(Data,1,function(x){sqrt(sum((x-Center)^2,na.rm=T))} );
return(Dist);
}
```

Data: Original Data.
Clusters: t(Medoids).
Medoids: 'medoids' picked by clara.
Dist2Center: A function which calculates Euclidean distance of each observation from each Medoids.

Behnam.

Comment: Have a look at the source code of Clara?

Comment: No. But I found the problem. I have that problem only when clara standardized the inputs. I did the same, but the difference is that (apparently) clara does the standardization one each sub set separately, while I was doing it on the whole data set together. When I don't do the standardization, no difference exists. B.

Comment: Having a look at the Clara C code, I found that Clara manipulates the distances if there is any missing values. The line " dsum *= (nobs / pp) " in the code shows that it counts the number of non-missing values in each pair of observations (nobs), divides it by the number of variables (pp) and multiplies this by the sum of squares. That is why it does not give the same results as my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happens only when input data has NA values. For inputs without NAs, the results of my algorithm and clara are identical. I think this is related to how clara handles NA values while calculating the distances of observations to medoids. Any comment? Any suggestion for replacing clara with a better algorithm compatible with large datasets and NA values?

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at the Clara C code, I found that Clara manipulates the distances if there is any missing values. The line " dsum *= (nobs / pp) " in the code shows that it counts the number of non-missing values in each pair of observations (nobs), divides it by the number of variables (pp) and multiplies this by the sum of squares. That is why it does not give the same results as my algorithm.